# Get TokenAccess from Azure Active Directory from a sh script

Tags: shell, azure, sh, azure-active-directory, adal

Given the AppId, KeyId (or secret) and other information like the ResourceId, TenantId, etc...

Is there a way I can get an access token from Azure Active Directory on my .sh script?

I was able to do that on my Node JS script and also in manage code using ADAL but I haven't been able to figure this out for shell files.

Any documentation and sample code available?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` to make the necessary http requests and parse the responses.

There are [some docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-client-creds#get-a-token) that include curl in the examples, and using the sample requests in the others, you can figure out what to send.

Comment: But that means then I need to have a service wrote by me to provide the access token right? I am asking about adal support on sh scripts

Comment: There isn't any library for sh scripts, so you need to code the http requests yourself. As I understand it, you have an application already, and you want to retrieve an access token for it. Then you only need two http requests, one to sign in and get the ID token, and then one to retrieve the access token for your application. If that is the use case, and you already have working Node JS code, couldn't you write a simple cmd line tool which retrieves the token and lets you use it from your script.

Comment: Deleting my old answer. Actually, I am not quite sure what you are saying... the NodeJS is just a script that uses the adal module to get an access token and then I use it to call my service. I am not sure what my Node JS code has to do here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to accomplish. I assumed that your existing code to retrieve the access token could be invoked from your shell script. If not, then you can use curl to accomplish the same.

Comment: yeah, that's what I am trying to figure out. Using CURL, how do I do a HTTP request to Azure with a ClientID and AppKey so I can get an access token that I can use to authorize against my service?